# Remove original element after drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a modified version of this fiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/30/)

I would like to know how to hide or make undraggable the original element if it has been placed on a correct box.

Eg. If i drag box "I am 4" onto a box that accepts it , the box stays there . The original box should be disabled from being dragged to another box.

JS CODE :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(".DragItem").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function(){
        $(this).data("origPosition",$(this).position());
        },
    helper: "clone"
});

$(".DropItem").droppable({
    accept: ".DragItem",
    over: hover_drop,
    out: out_drop,
    drop: function( event, ui ) { 
            if($(this).attr("id").indexOf($(ui.draggable).attr("id")) > -1)
                { 
                  $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone()); 
                  $(this).removeClass('DropTargetValid DropTargetInvalid');
                } 
                else 
                { 
                  var newrrr =  $(ui.helper).clone();       
                  $(this).append(newrrr);
                  newrrr.animate(ui.draggable.data().origPosition,"slow").fadeOut("slow"); 
                  $(this).removeClass('DropTargetValid DropTargetInvalid'); 
                }
    }
});

function hover_drop( event, ui ) { 
        //console.log($(ui.draggable).position());
        if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf($(ui.draggable).attr("id")) > -1){
            $(this).addClass('DropTargetValid');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('DropTargetInvalid');
        }
    }
function out_drop( event, ui ) { 
            $(this).removeClass('DropTargetValid DropTargetInvalid');
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply don't use clone ?

http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/35/

```
$(".DragItem").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$(".drop1").droppable({
    accept: '#1,#2,#3',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid'

});

$(".drop2").droppable({
    accept: '#2,#3',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid'

});

$(".drop3").droppable({
    accept: '#3,#4',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid'

});

$(".drop4").droppable({
    accept: '.DragItem',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid'

});
```

But if you really want to keep them on top :

http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/42/

```
$(".drop1").droppable({
    accept: '#1,#2,#3',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid',
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(ev.target).draggable( 'disable' );
        $(ev.target).append(ui.draggable.clone());

    }
});
```

And if you want to enable them back :

```
$("myselector").draggable('enable');
```

**Fixed :**

http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/45/

```
$(".drop1").droppable({
    accept: '#1,#2,#3',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid',
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        var id = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        $(ev.target).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        $("#" + id).draggable('disable');  
    }
});
```

Comment: draggable('disable') it's the answer

Comment: @MrPk Im using the code above (2nd one) and i get this error Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable' . It makes the green color stick on other boxes

Comment: Can you show us what you did, because the second fiddler link is working properly for me.

Comment: @MrPk Iv not done anything . I literally copied the code from the js fiddle . I can drag and drop , but if there is more than one place a box can go , it will cause the box to stay green even after the item has been droped on another.

Comment: to me works perfectly, so maybe it's a browser issue. Wich one you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Added new id to your html "dragFromHere". 
Please check updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/32/

```
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;" id="dragFromHere">
    <div id="1" class="DragItem drag1">I am 1</div>
    <div id="2" class="DragItem drag1">I am 2</div>
    <div id="3" class="DragItem drag2">I am 3</div>
    <div id="4" class="DragItem drag2">I am 4</div>
</div
```

and in JS add following line.

```
$(".drop1").droppable({
    accept: '#1,#2,#3',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid',
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(ev.target).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        $('#dragFromHere').find('#1').remove();
    }
});
```